# Repeated Segmentation Fault while deleting from a Linked List in C

Tags: c, dictionary, linked-list, segmentation-fault, abstract-data-type

For an assignment we are told to create a Dictionary Abstract Data Type (ADT) which is based on a linked list structure in C.

From all my tests using the required functions

size
insert (being done at the tail using a tail node)
delete
makeEmpty

The client I've written tests all of these and I haven't had any problems.

But when using a grading script that is provided I get segmentation faults.

The script adds a thousand entries to a 'Dictionary'

does a few steps that are unrelated

deletes entries from 901 to 1000, meaning its deleting from the middle of the linked list

I get to this point without an issue but the next part causes a seg fault

when the script tries to delete from 900 down, and at 772 I always get a seg fault

I've tried to recreate with a smaller sample by adding 10 entries to 'dictionary'

deleting 9 and 10

then trying to delete from 8 down and I dont get the same problem?

here is my delete function, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
void delete(Dictionary D, char* key){
   Node N;
//Nodes are pointers to NodeObj's which are structs that have a key,a value, and a Node which points to //the next in the list
   Node P = NULL;      

   N = find(D, key);//returns the desired Node


   if(N == D->head){//D-> head is a field in a Dictionary struct which is a Node that has no value and //points to the first NodeObj in the list

      D->head = N->next;
      if(N == D->tail)D->tail = NULL;//D->tail is the same thing as head, but pointing to the last //NodeObj

   }else if(N == D->tail){

      D->tail = findPreviousNode(D, N->key);

   }else{

      P = findPreviousNode(D, N->key);
      P->next = N->next;

   }

   N->next = NULL;
   freeNode(&N);
   N = NULL;
   D->numItems--;



}
```

I've ommited some precondition checking for none of the conditions are being tripped to cause the problem

EDIT:

I think I might have left some crucial information omitted.

In my program a Dictionary is a typedef for a pointer to a DictionaryObj. Which has fields for a head Node, a tail Node, and its size.

A Node is a pointer to a NodeObj, which has fields for a key, value, and a Node field in order to point to the next NodeObj in the linked list.

So delete() is passed a pointer to a DictionaryObj which has a head field that 
points to the first NodeObj, from their you can follow each NodeObj's next 
field.

I thought I had covered the case when deleting the node which is pointed to by the DictionaryObj's head field by reassigning the head field to point to the next node in the list, which is obtained by following the Node pointer in that NodeObj.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). Your `delete` function must pass the *address of* the original pointer not just a pointer to head. That way if you delete the first node, you can update the original pointer to hold the new address for the new `head` node. Your `typedef` of a pointer in `Dictionary` partially masks that problem. [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) may be helpful.

Comment: See also: [Error deleting node from first position in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731270/error-deleting-node-from-first-position-in-c/36733255#36733255) and [Trouble with changing pointer values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444545/trouble-with-changing-pointer-values)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, I unfortunately don't fully understand your suggestions, and I felt it might have had to do with my lack of explanation. I have edited the original post to add more detail that might be pertinent.

Comment: If you look further in your code, you probably have a `typedef stuct node* Dictionary;`. So the type of the node in your linked list is actually something like `struct node*` not `Dictionary` (which is just an alias). In your `delete` function, you must pass `struct node **D` or `Dictionary *D` in order to pass the actual address of whatever your `head` node is (e.g `delete (&head, key)`, not `delete (head, key)`. That way your `delete` function receives the actual **address of** the `head` node and not a *copy-of* the pointer. *Read my answers in the links above...*

Comment: In order to provide a definite answer, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hang on, there's mention of a `Dictionary` type, and a `find` function that uses a `char *key` (should probably be `const char *`, btw). You also say there's a linked list behind it all. What exactly are you implementing? A linked list, or a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was when I was deleting from the end of the Linked list, I was properly pointing the tail node of the dictionary to the previous node from that which is being deleted. But I wasn't making sure to point the previous node's 'next' value to NULL, because there wouldn't be anything after it.

it should have been

```
}else if(N == D->tail){

      P = findPreviousNode(D, N->key);
      D->tail = P
      P->next = NULL;

   }else{
```